# What is this "Authorization Server" that's referred to in Spring's api doc for OAuth2LoginConfigurer.UserInfoEndpointConfig?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I followed a [tutorial](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/oauth2-login-with-google-example) for a Spring Boot app that allows logging in with Google. It seems to work fine!

But I'm confused about part of the code in the class which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. Specifically, when it calls `HttpSecurity.oauth2Login().userInfoEndpoint().userService(OAuth2UserService<>)`.

Here is the class description in Spring's [api documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/oauth2/client/OAuth2LoginConfigurer.UserInfoEndpointConfig.html) for `OAuth2LoginConfigurer.UserInfoEndpointConfig` (text bolded by me):

> Configuration options for the **Authorization Server's** UserInfo Endpoint.

So does this mean the app is running an authorization server? But `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` isn't included in the dependencies, only `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`. (Using Maven.)

- How do I know when/if my Spring Boot app has an authorization server?
- Does it need to have one in order to log in with Google using OAuth 2.0?
- Is it simply the fact that we're calling `HttpSecurity.oauth2Login()` that tells the Spring framework to create an authorization server (if there is one)?
- If the app (as written) has an authorization server, with a **UserInfo Endpoint**, how exposed is this endpoint by default?
- Would it be helpful to use `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`, and if so, for what?

I've been reading the [reference doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/index.html) for Spring Security, but I'm still confused.

Answer (score 0):

The `Authorization Server` is the server that authenticates your users and issues secure tokens (access tokens or ID tokens). It's a name used in the OAuth specification. In OpenID Connect it's called Open ID Connect Provider (OP). In your use case, the Authorization Server is Google, as you get the access token and ID token from Google. If you're issuing your own access token based on authentication from Google, then your service is the Authorization Server.

You can read about access to Google's userinfo endpoint here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#obtaininguserprofileinformation

A resource server is a server that consumes access tokens. Again, it's a name introduced by the OAuth spec. Very often it's the API that you call with the access token you got from the Authorization Server.

In Spring, the OAuth2 resource server package adds utilities for verifying access tokens, e.g. to verify JWTs or introspect opaque access tokens. You can add that dependency if you need to verify access tokens.

Comment: The Authorization Server is Google, so why am I calling a method to configure an Authorization Server's UserInfo Endpoint? I don't get to configure Google's server, right?

I'm talking about the method HttpSecurity.oauth2Login().userInfoEndpoint().userService().

Comment: You're not configuring the server. You're telling your application what is the address for the user info endpoint. Thanks to it your app will be able to call that endpoint to get some information about the user.